# How to launch a new instance of a Docker container on web request in Docker Swarm / Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I have a web API running on a Docker container. I want to implement a solution in Kubernetes/DockerSwarm such that a new instance of the container is created everytime the API is called. How can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to control the `docker swarm` from inside the container itself. This can be done in two steps:

1. install the docker inside the container. This depends on the container image. A solution can be like this:

   RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install docker.io 56 && usermod -g docker jenkins
2. mount the docker socket inside the container. For example, if you start the container manually, you need something like this:

   docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker ubuntu:latest bash

Now, you can run `docker` commands inside the container. You can, for example, inspect a service or scale it to a bigger number of replicas.

**You should note however that this solution is not very safe, if someone gains access to your container then it has access to the entire swarm, so be aware!**

Comment: Thanks for the response @Constantin.I got it done in Kubernetes via healthChecks